# How to quickly switch different project in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have to open each intellij instance for each application. And switch between these project are not so efficient. (there's no dependency between these project, so I can not add them into one project). I just wonder is there efficient way to switch between different projects in intellij.

Comment: a) you can open more than one IntelliJ workspace at the same time  b) is this for developing or running? If running, you could run outside of the IDE.

Comment: It is for developing.  Usually I need to check the source code of multiple project.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/opening-multiple-projects.html

Comment: You could create a 'holder' project in an empty directory, and add both projects as modules (created new, from source). This works for me and I'm in a similar position to you -- I'm writing a service that invokes another service, but which isn't a related project.

Comment: Try Frame Switcher plugin -- it allows to switch between recent and currently opened projects/frames via easy to use popup menu.

Answer (score 17):

**OSX**: Press CMD + `

**Windows/Linux**: Press cntr + `

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#switch-projects

Comment: The query was for IntelliJ & the link is broken

Comment: God bless your soul! My life won't be the same

Answer (score 10):

if you have several opened projects: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-multiple-projects.html

you can use:

Next Project Window: <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>

or

Previous Project Window: <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>

**Edit**

jebrains update their Switching Between Open Projects:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/switching-between-projects.html

Next Project Window: <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

or

Previous Project Window: <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Set up a keymap shortcut to "Manage Projects...".

This brings up a window that you can type into to quickly search recent projects. It includes currently open projects as well as previously closed projects.

Comment: Best solution so far

Answer (score 4):

Use search everywhere command (`shift + shift`) and type `Open Recent` - you will be able to switch to one of your recent projects.

You could also configure any shortcut you want for this action.
To create shortcut, go to `Preferences->Keymap` and find `Main menu->File->Open Recent`.

Comment: The mapping to the submenu is a great. (who knew you could do that?) On macOS, `CMD+backtick` is simply too  unreliable if you have more than 2 projects open: sometimes you get the last window, sometimes you don't

Answer (score 4):

Try this https://github.com/krasa/FrameSwitcher.

Switching intelliJ windows by searching project name.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a MacOS user: As well as the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> keyboard shortcuts which IntelliJ offers to toggle between IntelliJ windows, the OS-level <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> keyboard shortcut is an excellent way to see and navigate between windows of the current app. The screenshot below shows the view which it offers. If you turn on App Exposé in your Trackpad preferences, you can also get to this view by swiping down with three fingers.

[image: Screenshot of showing all open windows for the current app]

Answer (score 0):

To switch between open projects, you can use the following commands of the Window menu:

Window | Next Project Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
Window | Previous Project Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: This only works if you have previously chosen to open each project in its own window.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what do you want it to be?
Go to settings, select keymap, and search for project.

There you will find the next and previous projects.. you can apply them or change them if you find them convenient. I chose (option + right arrow) for next and (option + left arrow) for previous.

[image]